# inverting the first three elementary symmetric polynomials

Tags: symmetric-polynomials, roots-of-cubics

Given the first three elementary symmetric polynomials $e_1 = x_1 + x_2 + x_3$, $e_2 = x_1 x_2 + x_1 x_3 + x_2 x_3$, $e_3 = x_1 x_2 x_3$ (where $x_1, x_2, x_3 \ge 0$), I wish to solve these equations to express $x_1, x_2, x_3$ in terms of $e_1, e_2, e_3$ as simply as possible.

As long as $e_1, e_2, e_3 \ge 0$, a unique (non-negative) solution can be shown to exist by eliminating any two variables, say $x_2, x_3$, to obtain a cubic equation for the remaining variable of the form $x_1^3 - e_1 x_1^2 + e_2 x_1 - e_3$, which by Descarte's rule of signs should have 1 or 3 positive solutions, and also (via the substitution $x_1 \rightarrow -x_1$) no negative solutions, so this cubic always has a single positive solution. Thus the equations themselves should always have a unique non-negative solution, which could be obtained from Cardano's formula or via the usual trigonometric formula.

The question is "is there a simple and symmetric way of expressing the unique solution to this system of equations that does not explicitly use complex numbers or trigonometric functions?"

Comment: Probably not. Quoting from this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#History) in Wikipedia, "The solution in radicals (without trigonometric functions) of a general cubic equation, when all three of its roots are real numbers, contains the square roots of negative numbers, a situation that cannot be rectified by factoring aided by the rational root test, if the cubic is irreducible; this is the so-called *casus irreducibilis* ("irreducible case"). This conundrum led Italian mathematician Gerolamo Cardano to conceive of complex numbers in around 1545 in his Ars Magna (...)"